# What's the best moment to commit to the DB a row inserted to the DataGridView control?

Tags: datagridview, insert

What's the best moment to commit to the DB a row inserted to the DataGridView control?

Comment: Perhaps more detail to the question?
Do you mean write or commit?
What about transaction length, DB type/location/speed?
How do you want to manage the data grid, will a user be able to undo/redo/cancel?
How interactive is the DB, does another user need to see this information the very second it might exist?

Comment: I'm using mssql server on my desktop. I mean commit to the db after adding a row to the datagridview control. It's a row from the Products table of the northwind db.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to add a 'commit' button that the user clicks after the new row has been added (and the cells written). This way the changes in the row are properly recorder for the commit / update can happen.

If you really want to commit immediately after any kind of change, then commit to DB on e.g. `DataGridView::CellValueChanged` event.

If there is no user interaction with the row, you can simply commit everything at the end of the insert procedure, since there is no need for `DataRow::EndEdit()` function.